# Use typeof inside type definition

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public void Include<T>(IQueryable<T> source) {

  MethodInfo include = typeof(EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions)
    .GetMethods()
    .First(x => x.Name == "Include" && x.GetParameters()
    .Select(y => y.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition())
    .SequenceEqual(new[] { typeof(IQueryable<>), typeof(Expression<>) }));

  LambdaExpression lambda = GetTestLambdaExpression<T>();

  MethodInfo method = include.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), lambda.ReturnType);           

  IIncludableQueryable<T, lambda.ReturnType> result = (IIncludableQueryable<T, lambda.ReturnType>)method.Invoke(null, new Object[] { source, parameter });

}
```

I know the method.Invoke will return a IIncludableQueryable. But I get a compilation error on this:

```
'lambda' is a variable but is used like a type
```

Comment: Always include the error message.

Comment: Care to share the error?

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Just updated my question

Comment: This is about your 600th question. Your research is missing, there's hundreds of duplicates. What have you tried?

Comment: You're confusing types with instances of `Type`! You cannot go back to generics once you go down the reflection path.

Comment: You'll have to add an additional generic parameter to the `Include()` method in order to represent the `TProperty`. But, since the method doesn't actually `return` anything, why do you need `result` to be of the actual `IIncludableQueryable<T, TProperty>` type?

Comment: @haim770 The method does not return anything but it will ...

Comment: @CodeCaster The problem is I am trying to overcome an Entity Framework Core limitation which is that Include method does not allow paths definition as strings .. So I am trying various approaches but I always end up with a problem ...

Comment: You can't do what you want. Generics and castings are resolved at compile time, so you can't use a variable (whose value is only known at runtime) inside a casting (or generic definition). You could use `dynamic` for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IIncludableQueryable<T, lambda.ReturnType>
```

You cannot do this. Generics need a compile-time type, but the second generic parameter is a runtime type. You need to use reflection as you did in the line before if you want to use types unknown at compile time for generics.

Comment: `dynamic` might be simpler... couldn't say "better", but definitely simpler. Once you need to get into reflection for generics, it tends to get really messy :-)

But yes, the answer is 100% correct